# Question about the Twelvefoldway position 12(all elements indistinguishable, surjective) How do you compute it?

Tags: combinatorics

I don't understand how to compute this. Lets say I had $P_3(8)$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) gives the recursive formula $P_n(m) = P_{n−1}(m − 1) + P_n(m − n)$. I don't know what to do with it. In other words I want to know how to find the number of partitions of $n$ into $m$ parts.

Comment: Your question is unclear and unformatted.

Comment: The 3 would be smaller in visual size than P or 8 if properly formatted. Are you familiar with the twelvefold way?

Comment: @Bob: Is my edit the notation that you intended?

Comment: What I'd do with it is put $n=3$ and $m=8$ and then the formula gives me $P_3(8)=P_2(7)+P_3(5).$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to run the calculation out to a number:

\begin{align}
P_3(8) &= P_2(7) &&\hskip{-2em} + P_3(5)\\
 &= \color{blue}{P_1(6)} + P_2(5)  &&\hskip{-2em} + P_2(4) + \color{red}{P_3(2)}\\
 &= 1 + \color{blue}{P_1(4)} + P_2(3) &&\hskip{-2em}+ \color{blue}{P_1(3)} +  P_2(2)+ 0\\
 &= 1 + 1 + \color{blue}{P_1(2)} +\color{red}{P_2(1)} &&\hskip{-2em}+ 1 +  \color{blue}{P_1(1)} + \color{red}{P_2(0)} + 0\\
 &= 1 + 1 + 1 +0 &&\hskip{-2em} + 1 +  1 + 0 + 0\\
&= 5\\
\end{align}

where the blue terms ($P_1(m)$, with $m>0$) are known to be one and the red terms ($P_n(m)$, with $n>m$) known to be zero.